# Intent Filter for Custom File extension does not work in Android 6 Marshmallow

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-6.0-marshmallow

With Android < 6 I have no problem opening downloaded files with my application but with Android 6 the intent filters do not seem to work.

I have the following intent filters in my application:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.dd35" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="content"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.dd35" />
        </intent-filter>
```

When debugging I can see why it does not work:

```
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/4 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3}
```

So apparently the downloaded file is given to the intent as a file with name 4 without any extension. How can I create an intent filter now that opens the correct files (with `.dd35` extension) and not all downloaded files..?

It should work on Android 6 with the native file manager (the Downloads app). It already works for Astro and other filemanagers with the intent filters above because they **do** trigger nicely the intent with the filename and extension.

Comment: So 4 is not a .dd35 file? Is that what you said? To retrieve the file name you should use the content resolver. Something with display name.

Comment: `that opens the correct files and not all downloaded files`. You mean: that only opens files with .dd35 extension?

Comment: Which app does the user use to select files? Try other apps.

Comment: @greenapps exactly! file "4" is on the sdcard saved as .dd35 but the intent trigger does not contain the filename in Android 6 for some reason. I want it to work with the default android file manager (downloads). With other file managers like Astro it works.

Comment: I already told you that you get a complete different content resolver path. Not a file system path. I also told you how to retrieve the original file name. You have not confirmed or denied the things i wrote. Why not?

Comment: `default android file manager (downloads). `  ????????????

Comment: @greenapps yes, if you go to the apps menu in Android 6 (depending perhaps the vendor though), you can see an app called Downloads, here you can view a list of recently downloaded items and click them to open them. Also when you download a file you get a popup to open the file immediately, this uses the same system. I do not deny the things you write because it is true, but that doesn't make the intent filter work correctly. I want it to only open the files with the special extension and not all files...

Answer (score 0):

We need to use different **mimeType** and **scheme**

First you have to add read external storage permission in androidmanifest.xml file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then in the androidmanifest file in the Activity tag, you add an intent-filter as shown below.

```
 <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType= "application/zip" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```